# systemd timer on boot but not too often

Tags: systemd, scheduling, systemd-timer

Would it be possible to create a timer that will run a service on a boot, but not more often than once a week?

In my case it would be beneficial to run a TRIM (`fstrim`) for SSD disk on a boot, but once that happened I'd like to wait one week just in case I will reboot the system a few times that day.

The internal logic would be that on boot the timer will check the last execution time and when the last execution time has happened in the last 7 days it won't executes it nor updates the last execution time.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

The following timer file is from [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/W%C3%B6chentliches_fstrim_ab_Ubuntu_18.04#), but it's basically the default for many systems. Your system might actually include one, it may be under `/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer` or you can check with `systemctl status fstrim.timer`

`fstrim.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks once a week
Documentation=man:fstrim

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
AccuracySec=1h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

This will run once a week, if you leave your pc running - and immediately if you miss the last time (turn it back on after more than a week) (also see [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers): RealTime Timer):

> When activated, it triggers the service immediately if it missed the
> last start time (option Persistent=true), for example due to the
> system being powered off